# DLL file is missing in the Debug folder after debugging the application in a VS-2008 Windows Application

Tags: c#

After debugging my application, the Debug folder only contains executable and .vshost files, but no DLL files.

Comment: But does it work?.. Unless you're referencing additional library projects or external libraries, why should there be a .dll file?

Comment: a DLL will only be built if your project includes libraries not in the core framework, or has it's own libraries built from soruce

Comment: Is your dll built from your solution projects or is it an external library?

Comment: What do you mean "**after** debugging my application"? Are you implying that the dll files existed before running the application? Otherwise, you can force Visual Studio to include dll files in your build folder by selecting `Copy Local` in the reference's properties. If you're not using any external libraries, then you don't need to include those files with your executable.